# Help With A Handwritten Sentence

Tags: handwriting

I'm reading a short omake and can't quite decipher some handwritten text:

[image]

I'm fairly sure one of the characters is 生 but can't tell for the rest.

Comment: it says それでね，先生がー.

Comment: @ishikun 回答は回答欄に

Comment: @永劫回帰 off-topic なのかなと思ってあえてコメントにしました

Comment: @永劫回帰 返答にしました、ありがとうございます

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is on-topic but it says:

> それでね，先生がー.